# TFLite Model Not Analyzing Bitmap

Tags: tensorflow, android-intent, tensorflow-lite, android-bitmap

I cannot identify precisely what the problem is, but I know it is a problem with how a TFLite model is receiving a bitmap, as I tried sending it a different way through calling the Camera intent and it worked as intended by doing that, but I cannot call the Camera Intent as it will pull up the Camera screen, which I aim to not do.

Both versions of this code use the same tflite model, so I know it is not a model issue.

Working version:

```
        picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
    }

    public void classifyImage(Bitmap image){
        try {
            Model model = Model.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
            TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 224, 224, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * imageSize * imageSize * 3);
            byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            int [] intValues = new int[imageSize * imageSize];
            image.getPixels(intValues, 0, image.getWidth(), 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            int pixel = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < imageSize; j++){
                    int val = intValues[pixel++]; // RGB
                    byteBuffer.putFloat(((val >> 16) & 0xFF) * (1.f / 255.f));
                    byteBuffer.putFloat(((val >> 8) & 0xFF) * (1.f / 255.f));
                    byteBuffer.putFloat((val & 0xFF) * (1.f / 255.f));
                }
            }
            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);
            Model.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
            TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();
            float[] confidences = outputFeature0.getFloatArray();
            int maxPos = 0;
            float maxConfidence = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < confidences.length; i++){
                if(confidences[i] > maxConfidence){
                    maxConfidence = confidences[i];
                    maxPos = i;
                }
            }
            String[] classes = {"Banana", "Orange", "Pen", "Sticky Notes"};
            result.setText(classes[maxPos]);
            String s = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){
                s += String.format("%s: %.1f%%\n", classes[i], confidences[i] * 100);
            }
            confidence.setText(s);
            model.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            int dimension = Math.min(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            image = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(image, dimension, dimension);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

            image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, imageSize, imageSize, false);
            classifyImage(image);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Nonworking version:
This version will always return the same confidences (changes depending on different tflite models being used) no matter the image.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer, View.OnClickListener {
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;

    PreviewView previewView;
    private ImageCapture imageCapture;
    private Button bCapture;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                startCameraX(cameraProvider);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, getExecutor());

    }

    Executor getExecutor() {
        return ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
    }

    private void startCameraX(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
        cameraProvider.unbindAll();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();
        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .build();
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        // Image capture use case
        imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                .build();
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle( this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture);
    }



    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.bCapture:
                capturePhoto();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void capturePhoto() {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        imageCapture.takePicture(
                new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
                        getContentResolver(),
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        contentValues
                ).build(),
                getExecutor(),
                new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Photo has been saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getLastImageId());
                        int dimension = Math.min(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
                        image = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(image, dimension, dimension);
                        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 224, 224, false);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
                        classifyImage(image);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error saving photo: " + exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );

    }
    private String getLastImageId(){
        final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";
        Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);
        if(imageCursor.moveToFirst()){
            @SuppressLint("Range") String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            imageCursor.close();
            System.out.println(fullPath);
            return fullPath;
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }

    private void classifyImage(Bitmap image) {
        try {
            Model model = Model.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

            // Creates inputs for reference.
            TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 224, 224, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*224*224*3);
            byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            int[] intValues = new int[224*224];
            image.getPixels(intValues, 0, image.getWidth(), 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            int pixel = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < 224; i++) {
                        int val = intValues[pixel++];
                        byteBuffer.putFloat(((val >> 16) & 0xFF) * (1.f/255.f));
                        byteBuffer.putFloat(((val >> 8) & 0xFF) * (1.f/255.f));
                        byteBuffer.putFloat(((val  & 0xFF) * (1.f/255.f)));
                    }
            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

            // Runs model inference and gets result.
            Model.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
            TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();
            float[] conifdences = outputFeature0.getFloatArray();
            int maxPos = 0;
            float maxConf = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < conifdences.length; i++) {
                if(conifdences[i] > maxConf) {
                    maxConf = conifdences[i];
                    maxPos = i;
                }
            }
            String[] classes = {"chicken", "apple", "things", "things"};
            System.out.println(classes[maxPos]);
            String s = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
                s+= String.format("%s: %.1f%%\n", classes[i], conifdences[i]*100);
            }
            System.out.println(s);
            // Releases model resources if no longer used.
            model.close();
          }

}
```